# Edit text from the preview pane in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way to configure Windows Explorer so as to be able to edit text from the preview pane, when previewing text files?

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: What have you researched and/or attempted so far?

Comment: @CharlieRB I have researched Google and attempted to edit, no luck so far.

Comment: I have looked and did not find anything either. I do not think it is possible since the preview pane only has simple reader type functionality. Otherwise, I think they would have called it the editing pane.

Comment: @CharlieRB I also think it is not possible because its only a viewer for not only texts but variety of file types like .docx, xlsx, .PDF, jpg etc...on second thought, it would be a hack of a lifetime if someone manages to do this because they would really have to pull the guts out of explorer.exe  :-D Also, software vendors would not like it too

Comment: Maybe through writing a dedicated handler? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnmagazine/archive/2007/01/04/1413218.aspx ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144144(v=vs.85).aspx though maybe read-only.

Comment: Would be a very interesting third party software.